# How to prevent offsetting a margin?

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, geometry, documentclass-writing

I have basic class file and I would like to use fancyhdr. Here is the markup of some-class.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{some-class}[2013/07/29]

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{
    \setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}
}
\DeclareOption{landscape} {
    \setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
    \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}
}

%Default options for design
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper}
%Process user given options
\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage[top=20mm, bottom=25mm, left=25mm, right=0mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{normal}{
  \fancyhf{} % this clears all six fields (left, center, right in header and footer)
  \fancyhead[C]{\thepage. oldal}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
  \headsep 20mm
}
\pagestyle{normal}
```

Content of my document.tex:

```
\documentclass[]{some-class}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{roncsak}
\title{some title}
\date{2013/07/28}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

When don't use fancyhdr package every margin I set are what I wanted. But when I'm using \headsep command the whole document (except header) gets an offset of 20 mm. It would be ok but in this case the bottom margin is 'disappearing'.

I would like to use some kind of code that could subtract from \textlength, or make margin "sticky".

Do you know something like this?

Comment: Why is that `\headsep` inside the pagestyle and not a general part of the page layout, it has nothing to do there.

Comment: I don't know of any `\textlength`, do you mean `\textheight`? And `\addtolength{\textheight}{-20mm}` is what you are looking for?

Comment: I would take your suggestion, @daleif !

Comment: @karlkoeller, I had meant that, and your code is what I was looking for! Thank you, all! (How could I accept your answer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are going to have in your class file, but I think you want to modify the value of `textheight`.

To do that (supposing you want to reduce that value of an amount=20mm) add this line to your file:

```
\addtolength{\textheight}{-20mm}
```